# Is there a better way to set keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and because of conflicts between a couple of extensions, I need to change a lot of keyboard shortcuts.  I'm beyond sick of trying to use the tiny, non-resizable keyboard settings dialog box.  Is there a better way of managing your shortcuts?  Are there any extensions out there that I haven't found?  Are they saved in a text file somewhere that I can just crack open in a text editor and have at it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get Emacs style key bindings in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190402/how-can-i-get-emacs-style-key-bindings-in-visual-studio)